# PHP preg_match between text and the first occurrence of -

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to grab the 12345 out of the following URL using preg_match.

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/directory/12345-this-is-the-rest-of-the-url.html";

$beg = "http://www.somesite.com/directory/";
$close = "\-";
preg_match("($beg(.*)$close)", $url, $matches);
```

I have tried multiple combinations of . * ? \b

Does anyone know how to extract 12345 out of the URL with preg_match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things, first off, you need `preg_quote` and you also need delimiters.  Using your construction method:

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/directory/12345-this-is-the-rest-of-the-url.html";

$beg = preg_quote("http://www.somesite.com/directory/", '/');
$close = preg_quote("-", '/');
preg_match("/($beg(.*?)$close)/", $url, $matches);
```

But, I would write the query slightly differently:

```
preg_match('/directory\/(\d+)-/i', $url, $match);
```

It only matches the directory part, is far more readable, and ensures that you only get digits back (no strings)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use preg_match but would achieve the same thing and would execute faster:

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/directory/12345-this-is-the-rest-of-the-url.html";

$url_segments = explode("/", $url);
$last_segment = array_pop($url_segments);

list($id) = explode("-", $last_segment);

echo $id; // Prints 12345
```

Comment: actually that does not run any faster then the snippet ircmaxell provided (at least not by a measurable amount). During my testing sometimes your snippet and sometimes ircmaxell's snippet was faster. My snippet was nearly twice as fast though.

Comment: @yankee, Thanks for making the effort to test and sharing the results!

Answer (score 0):

Too slow, I am ^^.
Well, if you are not stuck on preg_match, here is a fast and readable alternative:

```
$num = (int)substr($url, strlen($beg));
```

(looking at your code I guessed, that the number you are looking for is a numeric id is it is typical for urls looking like that and will not be "12abc" or anything else.)

Comment: And what happens if the url submitted is `directory/123e45-`?  or `directory/e123`.  Or `directory/0123`?

Comment: @ircmaxell: Yes you are right in this case the the snippet would fail to comply to the question. I edited my answer to reflect this.